# How optimize this code use lambda expression

Tags: c#

I have code:

```
protected void Method1(List<SomeClass> mylist)
{
    foreach(var item in mylist)
    {
        if (!SomeClass.Validate(item))
        {
            continue;
        }
        DoStuff(item);
    }
}

protected void Method2(List<SomeClass> mylist)
{
    foreach(var item in mylist)
    {
        if (!SomeClass.Validate(item) || item.Value == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        DoStuff(item);
    }
}
```

how to organize these two methods?

they have a difference of only `item.Value == 0` can use lambda expressions.

I have no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void Method(List<SomeClass> mylist, Func<SomeClass, bool> filter)
{
    var selectedItem = mylist.Where(filter);

    foreach (var item in selectedItem)
        DoStuff(item);
}
```

So you can use:

```
Method(mylist, item => (SomeClass.Validate(item) && item.Value != 0));
```

Or:

```
Method(mylist, item => SomeClass.Validate(item));
```

Comment: +1, I wanted to write this as my second solution :) But I think it will be better if you'll write `mylist.Where(filter).ForEach(DoStuff)`

Comment: Wait, your solution doing stuff for wrong items. You need to rewrite filters

Comment: @RomanPekar you can NOT write `mylist.Where(filter).ForEach(DoStuff)` because .ForEach() is `List` Method not `IEnumerable`, if you have to, you should write: `mylist.Where(filter).ToList().ForEach(i=> DoStuff(i))`

Comment: Yes, thank you I just have no studio running to check. I'll change my solution

Comment: So basically you can write oneliner `mylist.Where(SomeClass.Validate).ToList().ForEach(DoStuff)` and
`mylist.Where(x => SomeClass.Validate(x) && x.Value != 0).ToList().ForEach(DoStuff)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you need, then the code should look like this.

```
protected void CommonMethod(List<SomeClass> mylist, Func<SomeClass, bool> predicate)
{
    foreach(var item in mylist)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            continue;
        }
        DoStuff(item);
    }
}

Func<SomeClass, bool> method1Predicate = (SomeClass item) => !SomeClass.Validate(item); 
Func<SomeClass, bool> method2Predicate = (SomeClass item) => !SomeClass.Validate(item) || item.Value == 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
protected void Method<T>(List<T> mylist, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var result = mylist.Where(predicate);   

    foreach(var item in result)
        DoStuff(item);
}
```

Comment: It isn't neccessary, the query returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, so I'll delete it, thanks.